# Custom View Broken When Window is Resized (Cocoa)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am experiencing this weird bug with my custom view. The custom view is supposed to show meters of rating distribution. It gets added to a cell view of an outline view.

When I resize the window, the custom view somehow gets squished and looks broken. I have pasted the `drawRect` of the custom view below.

[image]

```
override func drawRect(r: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(r)

    var goodRect: NSRect?
    var okRect: NSRect?
    var badRect: NSRect?
    let barHeight = CGFloat(10.0)

    if  self.goodPercent != 0.0 {
        goodRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: r.width * CGFloat(goodPercent), height: barHeight)
        let goodPath = NSBezierPath(roundedRect:  goodRect!, xRadius: 6, yRadius: 6)
        RatingDistributionView.goodColor.setFill()
        goodPath.fill()
    }

    if self.okPercent != 0.0 {
        let okX = CGFloat(goodRect?.width ?? 0.0)
        okRect = NSRect(x: okX, y: 0, width: r.width * CGFloat(okPercent), height: barHeight)
        let okPath = NSBezierPath(roundedRect:  okRect!, xRadius: 6, yRadius: 6)

        RatingDistributionView.okColor.setFill()
        okPath.fill()
    }

    if self.badPercent != 0.0 {
        var badX: CGFloat
        //Cases:
        //Good persent and OK present - badX = okRect.x + okRect.width
        //Good persent and OK missing - badX = goodRect.x + goodRect.width
        //Good missing and OK present - badX = okRect.x + okRect.width
        //Both missing -

        if okRect !=  nil {
            badX = okRect!.origin.x + okRect!.width
        }else if goodRect != nil {
            badX = goodRect!.origin.x + goodRect!.width
        } else {
            badX = 0.0
        }

        badRect = NSRect(x: badX, y: 0, width: r.width * CGFloat(badPercent), height: barHeight)
        let badPath = NSBezierPath(roundedRect:  badRect!, xRadius: 6, yRadius: 6)
        RatingDistributionView.badColor.setFill()
        badPath.fill()
    }

    //Draw dividers
    let divWidth = CGFloat(6.75)

    if self.goodPercent != 0.0 && (self.okPercent != 0.0 || self.badPercent != 0.0) {
        let divX = goodRect!.origin.x + goodRect!.width
        let divRect = NSRect(x: divX - (divWidth / 2.0), y: 0.0, width: divWidth, height: barHeight)
        let divPath = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: divRect, xRadius: 0, yRadius: 0)
        NSColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        divPath.fill()
    }

    if self.okPercent != 0.0 && self.badPercent != 0.0 {
        let divX = okRect!.origin.x + okRect!.width
        let divRect = NSRect(x: divX - (divWidth / 2.0), y: 0.0, width: divWidth, height: barHeight)
        let divPath = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: divRect, xRadius: 0, yRadius: 0)
        NSColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        divPath.fill()
    }
}
```

Comment: is it important to us BezierPath? can't you use Views

Comment: I'd like to keep the rounded corner..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `drawRect(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)`:

> dirtyRect:
>   A rectangle defining the portion of the view that requires redrawing. This rectangle usually represents the portion of the view that requires updating. When responsive scrolling is enabled, this rectangle can also represent a nonvisible portion of the view that AppKit wants to cache.

Don't use `dirtyRect` for your calculations, use `self.bounds`.

Answer (score 2):

AN alternative solution for your problem is to use NSView. You can have a container view with rounded corner and then drawing subviews (red, orange, green) in that container. like this;

[image]

I have written a class for it that you may customise according to your requirements;

```
public class CProgressView:NSView {

    private lazy var goodView:NSView = {
        let viw:NSView = NSView(frame: NSRect.zero);
        viw.layer = CALayer();
        viw.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.greenColor().CGColor;
        self.addSubview(viw)
        return viw;
    } ();

    private lazy var okView:NSView = {
        let viw:NSView = NSView(frame: NSRect.zero);
        viw.layer = CALayer();
        viw.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.orangeColor().CGColor;
        self.addSubview(viw)
        return viw;
    } ();

    private lazy var badView:NSView = {
        let viw:NSView = NSView(frame: NSRect.zero);
        viw.layer = CALayer();
        viw.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor;
        self.addSubview(viw)
        return viw;
    } ();

    private var _goodProgress:CGFloat = 33;
    private var _okProgress:CGFloat = 33;
    private var _badProgress:CGFloat = 34;

    private var goodViewFrame:NSRect {
        get {
            let rect:NSRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.frame.size.width * (_goodProgress / 100.0)), height: self.frame.size.height);
            return rect;
        }
    }

    private var okViewFrame:NSRect {
        get {
            let rect:NSRect = NSRect(x: self.goodViewFrame.size.width, y: 0, width: (self.frame.size.width * (_okProgress / 100.0)), height: self.frame.size.height);
            return rect;
        }
    }


    private var badViewFrame:NSRect {
        get {
            let width:CGFloat = (self.frame.size.width * (_badProgress / 100.0));
            let rect:NSRect = NSRect(x: self.frame.size.width - width, y: 0, width: width, height: self.frame.size.height);
            return rect;
        }
    }

    override public init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect);
        //--
        self.commonInit();
    }

    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder);
    }

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib();
        //--
        self.commonInit();
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        self.layer = CALayer();
        self.layer!.cornerRadius = 15;
        self.layer!.masksToBounds = true
        //-
        self.updateFrames();
    }

    public func updateProgress(goodProgressV:Int, okProgressV:Int, badProgressV:Int) {
        guard ((goodProgressV + okProgressV + badProgressV) == 100) else {
            NSLog("Total should be 100%");
            return;
        }

        _goodProgress = CGFloat(goodProgressV);
        _okProgress = CGFloat(okProgressV);
        _badProgress = CGFloat(badProgressV);
        //--
        self.updateFrames();
    }

    private func updateFrames() {
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.grayColor().CGColor;

        self.goodView.frame = self.goodViewFrame;
        self.okView.frame = self.okViewFrame;
        self.badView.frame = self.badViewFrame;
    }

    public override func resizeSubviewsWithOldSize(oldSize: NSSize) {
        super.resizeSubviewsWithOldSize(oldSize);
        //--
        self.updateFrames();
    }

}
```

**Note:** Call updateProgress() method for changing progress default is 33, 33 & 34 (33+33+34 = 100);

You may also download a sample project from the link below;

http://www.filedropper.com/osxtest